# Text columns in front of form using {{form_label()}}

Tags: css, symfony

I am trying to reuse this old code to make some forms:

In a form.html.twig

```
<div class="row" style='margin-bottom: 5px'>
        <div style='white-space:nowrap'>
          <div class='col-xs-2'></div>
          <div class='col-xs-3' style='border-bottom:1px solid black;padding-bottom: 14px'><div style='float:right'>{{ form_label(form.class.variable, 'Text on one column and text on another column', {'label_attr':{'style':'margin-top:5px'}})}}</div>
          <div class='col-xs-3' style='border-bottom:1px solid black;padding-bottom: 5px'>{{ form_widget(form.class.variable, {'attr':{'style':'width:95px','placeholder':'RAW value'}})}}</div>
          <div class='col-xs-3'></div>
        </div>
```

I would like to have two columns before the form like on this picture:
[image: two columns]

Thank you for the hints!

Comment: You can try and check this question about two columns using labels https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736936/css-two-column-form

Comment: In that question, he wants  2 column of form fields. What I want is just two columns of text just before the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to customise your `form_label` block.

Have a look at the example [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html#adding-a-required-asterisk-to-field-labels)

EDIT:

Roughly, you're after something like this:

Your form theme (say, two_column_labels.html.twig):

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_row %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {{ form_label(form) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock form_row %}

{% block form_label %}
    {% if label_attr.extra_label is defined %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {% set orig_label = label %}
                {% set new_label_attr = [] %}
                {% for key,value in label_attr %}
                    {% if key != 'extra_label' %}
                        {% set new_label_attr = new_label_attr|merge({(key): value}) %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% set label = value %}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% set label_attr = new_label_attr %}
                {{ parent() }}
                {% set label = orig_label %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {{ parent() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% else %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock form_label %}
```

In your form field definition in your form class:

```
  'label' => 'Second Label',
  'label_attr' => array('extra_label' => 'First Label'),
```

In your form template:

```
{% form_theme form 'two_column_labels.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: Thank you Strnm! I read the document but I sitll do not know how to make the two columns. Could you give me a piece of code how to do it? Thank you so much!